# '@' in paste() in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R. I'm using 3.5.1. I'm trying to use a piece of code I got from someone else. I generate an object called `repcounts` that's something like this:

```
> repcounts
t c 
1 6 
> class(repcounts) 
[1] "integer"
> str(repcounts)
 Named int [1:2] 1 6
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "t" "c"
```

The next line of code is

```
paste(?~@~\rep count:?~@~\, paste(paste0(names(repcounts), repcounts), collapse=?~@~\_?~@~]))
```

I get an error here:

```
Error: unexpected '@' in "paste(?~@"
```

Same problem with just a portion of the line:

```
> paste(paste0(names(repcounts), repcounts), collapse=?~@~\_?~@~])
Error: unexpected '@' in "paste(paste0(names(repcounts), repcounts), collapse=?~@"
```

Does anyone recognize what this line is trying to do, and what the problem with '@' is?

Comment: I suspect the other guy copied and pasted from an editor that does syntax highlighting, and the formatting codes got copied along with the text. Ask him to send you the code again.

Comment: Hong Ooi is probably correct regarding the syntax highlighting.  The code should be something like this: paste("rep count:", paste(paste0(names(repcounts), repcounts), collapse="_"))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that command should be something like:

```
paste("rep count:", paste(paste0(names(repcounts), repcounts), collapse="_"))
```